# In c#, is there a lock or queue in Interlocked class?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

Interlocked.Increment

```
Increments a specified variable and stores the result, as an atomic operation.
```

So it means that when multiple threads call it simultaneously, the result is also right.

But I'm inquisitve that how does it implement this. When two threads call it simultaneously, Is there an order between them? Such as that one thread call it first and another one call it second. Like a queue.

Is my opinion right?

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/interlocked.cs

Comment: basically yes??a lock or a queue

Comment: I think there is a queue

Comment: @Daniel A. White, the link you provided is meaningless. It doesn't tell a story.

Comment: Raymond Chen explains it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/09/13/10448736.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jitter has specific awareness of methods like this.  Necessary because their implementation is highly processor-specific.

For both the x86 and x64 jitter, it will substitute the method call with the `LOCK XADD` machine code instruction.  A specific instruction available on Intel processors to atomically increment a variable.  A corner case is using it on a variable of type *long*, in 32-bit mode the jitter generates a call to a helper method inside the CLR to get the job done.  Named `COMInterlocked::ExchangeAdd64()`.  Which in turn uses assembly code to use the `LOCK CMPXCHG8B` machine code instruction available on x86 processors.  It will be something else yet on an ARM or Itanium processor, I don't have one readily available to check.

You can discover these details yourself by looking at the generated machine code with the Debug + Windows + Disassembly debugger window.

Answer (score 2):

What `Interlocked.Increment` does internally is an implementation detail. Different implementations (.Net 2 vs. .Net 4.5 vs. Mono2, etc.) may implement it entirely different.

E.g. The MS .Net implementation (on Windows) will use what boils down to a [`InterlockedExchangeAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call IIRC, but that is an implementation detail and subject to change.

How `InterlockedExchangeAdd` is implemented is a detail of the Windows kernel, and can differ from version to version or platform to platform or both. E.g. [Raymond Chen describes some possible implementations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/09/13/10448736.aspx) (yes, plural: implementations) that Windows may use in some form. It is usually some form of [LS/SC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-Link/Store-Conditional) and/or [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) (throw in some memory barriers for good measure) and those are considered lock-free and may depend on implementation details of the actual CPU.

E.g. mono may use [a `pthread_mutex`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/143e50f97d4f9af067eff34b126a631d22219afa/mono/utils/atomic.c#L119) or the Windows `Interlocked*` APIs or memory barries, etc... depending on the OS and platform you built mono for. That's an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on. Future mono versions could use something else. Then again even `pthread_mutex` has multiple implementations as well, which, you guessed it, are subject to change at any point in the future.